# Yahoo Messenger Broken after Update

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I tried to download and install Yahoo Messenger 11. The installation failed because pcre.dll could not be found. Now YM does not work at all and I am told it is already installed when I try to install it again. When I try to run it, it gives me an error saying `pcre.dll could not be found`. What can I do to fix this? I am using Windows Vista and I even done a system restore back to the previous day and still can not get Messenger to work (same error).

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo Messenger does not require any prerequisites to be installed.

PCRE.dll is part of "PCRE - Perl Compatible Regular Expressions library"

Please try re-downloading Yahoo Messenger

http://filehippo.com/download_yahoomessenger/

Comment: Spell check :) prerequisites

Comment: Why did you choose FileHippo over Yahoo's [own site](http://messenger.yahoo.com/)?

Comment: Yahoo along with many other companies (Google, Microsoft) often use "web based" installers, in my opinion these just add unnecessary waiting times and more possibility to fail. I am in no way associate with FileHippo they just provide the full download.